# Lumen emails sometimes fail with "Connection to tcp://smtp.mailgun.org:587 Timed Out" but not using Mailgun

Tags: laravel, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, lumen, amazon-ses

My system comprises of two API's built in Lumen (version 6), one creates a Mail job and sends it to an SQS queue, the other reads from the queue and processes the mail using Amazon SES.

Most of the time the email is successfully sent and received, however, sometimes I'm getting the following errors in Sentry (both errors at the same time)

`Swift_TransportException: Connection to tcp://smtp.mailgun.org:587 Timed Out`

&

`Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied"`

which results in the email never being received.

The weird thing is that I'm not using Mailgun, so I'm not sure why the error has a reference to Mailgun.

I've made sure the values in my `.env` file for both API's is correct

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_MAILER=ses
MAIL_HOST=XXX
MAIL_USERNAME=XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXX
```

And have checked that the config is being loaded correctly on the live server (ECS container) via `php artisan tinker` and `config('mail')` which shows

```
>>> config('mail')
=> [
     "driver" => "ses",
     "host" => "XXX",
     "port" => 587,
     "from" => [
       "address" => "hello@example.com",
       "name" => "Example",
     ],
     "encryption" => "tls",
     "username" => "XXX",
     "password" => "XXX",
     "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs",
     "markdown" => [
       "theme" => "default",
       "paths" => [
         "/var/www/app/resources/views/vendor/mail",
       ],
     ],
     "log_channel" => null,
   ]
```

I've also tried `php artisan cache:clear`, however I can't run `php artisan config:clear` since Lumen doesn't have that command.

Any ideas why some emails are failing with the above errors? Or how else I can go about debugging this?

Here's the contents of my `config/mail.php` for both API's

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
    | if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
    | for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
    |
    */

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Laravel / Lumen queue worker was pulling jobs off the SQS queue on staging (staging was misconfigured)

Solution was to create a separate SQS queue for staging, and update the `.env` to look at that